# Passing c++ lambda to C functions

Tags: c++, lambda, libuv

I am trying to wrap a C++ layer over libuv, and using lambda for callback functions. However gcc is erroring out.

Here is the minified version:

```
#include <uv.h>

class Test {

public:
  void on_conn(uv_stream_t *server, int status) {   }
  void test() {
    uv_tcp_t server;
    auto err = uv_listen((uv_stream_t*)&server,
             100,
             [this]  (uv_stream_s *server, int status) -> void {
               this->on_conn(server,status);
             });
  }
};

Test t;
```

The relevant declarations in libuv are:

```
#   define UV_EXTERN /* nothing */
struct uv_stream_s { ... };
typedef struct uv_stream_s uv_stream_t;
typedef void (*uv_connection_cb)(uv_stream_t* server, int status);
UV_EXTERN int uv_listen(uv_stream_t* stream, int backlog, uv_connection_cb cb);
```

The error g++ is giving:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.1.1 20160501
<<--ERROR--{reformatted}-->>
t.cpp:15:7: error: cannot convert 
         ‘Test::test()::<lambda(uv_stream_s*, int)>’ to 
‘uv_connection_cb {aka void (*)(uv_stream_s*, int)}’ 
 for argument ‘3’ to ‘int uv_listen(uv_stream_t*, int, uv_connection_cb)’        
 }));
```

What exactly is broken here ? Any way to make this work ?

UPDATE:

More fun .. this in body of lambda does something ; first call works, second doesn't.

```
int cfunc( void cb() );

class Test {
public:
  void d(){}
  void test() {
    cfunc( [=]  () {});
    cfunc( [=]  () { this->d(); });
    //cfunc( [this]  () { });
    //cfunc( [&this]  () { });
  }
};

t.cpp:10:34: error: cannot convert ‘Test::test()::<lambda()>’ to ‘void (*)()’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int cfunc(void (*)())’
 cfunc( [=]  () { this->d(); });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A capturing lambda cannot be converted to a function pointer, only a non-capturing can:

```
//Lambda captures 'this', and so cannot be converted to function pointer
[this](uv_stream_s *server, int status) -> void {
       this->on_conn(server,status);
    }
```

Comment: ok Thanx! ..  .. lambda doesn't creat thunks ... understandable.

Comment: @Vardhan a lambda _can_ be converted a function, but only if it doesn't capture anything :)

Comment: hmmm .. even std::bind() doesn't work, tried several variations;
Looks like will have to use the 'data' field provided by libuv to stuff this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a trick like the following one:

```
class Test;

struct my_uv_tcp_t: uv_tcp_t {
    Test *test;
};

class Test {
public:
    Test(): server{} { server.test = this; }

    void on_conn(uv_stream_t *server, int status) {   }

    static void cb(uv_stream_t *server, int status) {
        auto srv = static_cast<my_uv_tcp_t*>(server);
        srv->test->on_conn(server, status);
    }

    void test() {
        auto err = uv_listen((uv_stream_t*)&server, 100, Test::cb);
    }

private:
    my_uv_tcp_t server;
};
```

The stream is given back once something happens on it and the handle of it is nothing more than a naked pointer.
You can use that same stream to store the information of the controller (the instance of the `Test` class in your case) and cast the stream to its original form when you receive it.

Otherwise, use the `data` field that is part of the handle if it's still unused.

Answer (score 0):

It should be work. I had same problem, so I sent current object to lambda over handle object property.

```
   #include <uv.h>
    class Test {

    public:
      void on_conn(uv_stream_t *server, int status) {   }
      void test() {
        uv_tcp_t server;
        server.data = this;
        auto err = uv_listen((uv_stream_t*)&server,
                 100,
                 []  (uv_stream_s *server, int status) -> void {
                    auto self = (Test*)server->data;
                   self->on_conn(server,status);
                 });
      }
    };

    Test t;
```